# Understanding Dynamic Types in calldata

Tags: solidity, evm, solc, calldata, encoding

### Context

I have recently been interested in how calldata is formed and interpreted. The [Docs have a great section](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html#use-of-dynamic-types) on how Dynamic Types are encoded into calldata. However, in practice I have trouble understanding this structure with more complex structs.

---

### The Setup

I created two simple contracts to test how they encode and decode the struct. One contract simply forms a relatively complex struct ([I used DyDx's ActionArgs for a "real" example](https://github.com/cryptopixelfrog/DyDxFlashloanArb/blob/189aca85bc2ce9f03ee2571e06f73db58f9084e4/contracts/dydx/DyDxFlashLoan.sol#L39))


 Contract **PassItToMe** is simply used to receive the an array of action items. It doesn't do anything in particular, just lets me read the call data it receives.


 Contract **SimpleCallDataTest** forms a hardcoded ActionArgs struct array and then calls **PassItToMe**'s actionTest function, thats it.

 **Code Snippet**

```
interface IPassItToMe {
    function actionTest(Actions.ActionArgs[] memory actions) external;
}

contract SimpleCallDataTest {

    function actionCallDataTest(address contAddr) public {
        Actions.ActionArgs[] memory operations = new Actions.ActionArgs[](1);

        operations[0] = Actions.ActionArgs({
            actionType: Actions.ActionType.Call,
            accountId: 7,
            amount: Types.AssetAmount({
                sign: true,
                denomination: Types.AssetDenomination.Wei,
                ref: Types.AssetReference.Delta,
                value: 1000
            }),
            primaryMarketId: 8,
            secondaryMarketId: 9,
            otherAddress: address(this),
            otherAccountId: 5,
            data: abi.encode(
                    msg.sender,
                    1000
                )
        });
        IPassItToMe(contAddr).actionTest(operations);
    }

}
```

## Result

When we call the function *actionCallDataTest*, we can see the following is used as input to the CALL opcode.


[image: The resulting calldata]


**Raw Hex**

```
0x6a919f900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009000000000000000000000000e0679aa631740f3dae1d3ce302f1f3d45f3ed61d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000160000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000031c8e1cb963d9cc02fcbc5d0cf881bbb1ffaf15f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8
```

## The Problem

When I format the input into the 32byte words to make it more human readable, we see the following:


[image: Cleaned up calldata]


In the above I have added notes to what my understanding what each word maps to and the byte count.

## Issues:

- Line 4: What is this value? it looks like an offset but I dont know
  what for.
- Line 15: I understand that this is a offset for the start
  of the data attribute. Why is it 352? (0x160 = 352 decimal) I expected 448, as from this
  offset we can see the tail encoding for *data*

---

### My Question

What do I misunderstand about the two above issues? The above encoding is correct and all data is correctly decoded by **PassItToMe** but I don't understand how.

Comment: Kindly paste the hex as text, not as an image.

Comment: @dwardu Sure, I added it to the question text as it was too long to paste into a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Function Selector and Argument Encoding](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/abi-spec.html#function-selector-and-argument-encoding):

> All in all, a call to the function f with parameters `a_1, ..., a_n` is encoded as
>
> ```
> function_selector(f) enc((a_1, ..., a_n))
> ```

Therefore, the function arguments are encoded as a tuple. In our case, we have:

```
function actionTest(Actions.ActionArgs[] memory actions) external;
```

So the arguments of `actionTest` are encoded as a tuple of length 1, i.e.:

```
(Actions.ActionArgs[] memory actions,)
```

From the [Formal Specification of the ABI Encoding](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/abi-spec.html#formal-specification-of-the-encoding):

> We distinguish static and dynamic types. Static types are encoded in-place and dynamic types are encoded at a separately allocated location after the current block.
>
> Definition: The following types are called “dynamic”:
>
> 1. `bytes`
> 2. `string`
> 3. `T[]` for any `T`
> 4. `T[k]` for any dynamic `T` and any `k >= 0`
> 5. `(T1,...,Tk)` if `Ti` is dynamic for some `1 <= i <= k`
>
> All other types are called “static”.

Since `Actions.ActionArgs[]` is dynamic (by rule 3), by rule 5 the tuple `(Actions.ActionArgs[],)` is also dynamic. Therefore `actionTest`’s argument-list of  is encoded dynamically. Therefore at position 0x00 in the abi-encoded argument-list, we can find the position at which the first (and only) argument’s abi-encoded bytes will start.

Yes, it feels redundant, because for an argument-list of length 1, this value is always going to be `0x20`. But in the general case, if there had been more arguments, the value would have differed.

Applying these rules, the bytes are decodable as follows:

```
0x6a919f90
args@0x000:                                                 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020 head(args[0]) = where tail(args[0]) starts within args
args@0x020: args[0]@0x000:                                  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 actions.length
args@0x040: args[0]@0x020: actions@0x000:                   0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020 head(actions[0]) = where tail(actions[0]) starts within actions
args@0x060: args[0]@0x040: actions@0x020: actions[0]@0x000: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008 ActionType.Call
args@0x080: args[0]@0x060: actions@0x040: actions[0]@0x020: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007 accountId = 7
args@0x0a0: args[0]@0x080: actions@0x060: actions[0]@0x040: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 amount.sign = true
args@0x0c0: args[0]@0x0a0: actions@0x080: actions[0]@0x060: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 amount.denomination = AssetDenomination.Wei = 0
args@0x0e0: args[0]@0x0c0: actions@0x0a0: actions[0]@0x080: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 amount.ref = AssetReference.Delta = 0
args@0x100: args[0]@0x0e0: actions@0x0c0: actions[0]@0x0a0: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8 amount.value = 0x3e8 = 1000
args@0x120: args[0]@0x100: actions@0x0e0: actions[0]@0x0c0: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008 primaryMarketId = 8
args@0x140: args[0]@0x120: actions@0x100: actions[0]@0x0e0: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009 secondaryMarketId = 9
args@0x160: args[0]@0x140: actions@0x120: actions[0]@0x100: 000000000000000000000000e0679aa631740f3dae1d3ce302f1f3d45f3ed61d otherAddress
args@0x180: args[0]@0x160: actions@0x140: actions[0]@0x120: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005 otherAccountId = 5
args@0x1a0: args[0]@0x180: actions@0x160: actions[0]@0x140: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000160 where data starts within actions[0]
args@0x1c0: args[0]@0x1a0: actions@0x180: actions[0]@0x160: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040 byte-length of data = 64 bytes
args@0x1e0: args[0]@0x1c0: actions@0x1a0: actions[0]@0x180: 00000000000000000000000031c8e1cb963d9cc02fcbc5d0cf881bbb1ffaf15f msg.sender
args@0x200: args[0]@0x1e0: actions@0x1c0: actions[0]@0x1a0: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8 1000
```

Comment: Great write up @dwardi, thanks! The break down of the args[] and actions[] was very useful.